# How to replicate a curl command with the nodejs request module?

Tags: node.js, heroku, amazon-s3

How can I replicate this `curl` request:

```
$ curl "https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/herokusources/..." \
  -X PUT -H 'Content-Type:' --data-binary @temp/archive.tar.gz
```

With the node [request](https://github.com/request/request) module?

I need to do this to `PUT` a file up on AWS S3 and to match the signature provided by Heroku in the put_url from [Heroku's sources endpoint API output](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-and-release-using-the-api#sources-endpoint).

I have tried this (where `source` is the Heroku sources endpoint API output):

```
// PUT tarball
function(source, cb){
  putUrl = source.source_blob.put_url;
  urlObj = url.parse(putUrl);

  var options = {
    headers: {},
    method : 'PUT',
    url    : urlObj
  }

  fs.createReadStream('temp/archive.tar.gz')
    .pipe(request(
      options, 
      function(err, incoming, response){    
        if (err){
          cb(err);
        } else {
          cb(null, source);
        }
      }
    ));
}
```

But I get the following `SignatureDoesNotMatch` error.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Error>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
    <AWSAccessKeyId>AKIAJURUZ6XB34ESX54A</AWSAccessKeyId>
    <StringToSign>PUT\n\nfalse\n1424204099\n/heroku-sources-production/heroku.com/d1ed2f1f-4c81-43c8-9997-01706805fab8</StringToSign>
    <SignatureProvided>DKh8Y+c7nM/6vJr2pabvis3Gtsc=</SignatureProvided>
    <StringToSignBytes>50 55 54 0a 0a 66 61 6c 73 65 0a 31 34 32 34 32 30 34 30 39 39 0a 2f 68 65 72 6f 6b 75 2d 73 6f 75 72 63 65 73 2d 70 72 6f 64 75 63 74 69 6f 6e 2f 68 65 72 6f 6b 75 2e 63 6f 6d 2f 64 31 65 64 32 66 31 66 2d 34 63 38 31 2d 34 33 63 38 2d 39 39 39 37 2d 30 31 37 30 36 38 30 35 66 61 62 38</StringToSignBytes>
    <RequestId>A7F1C5F7A68613A9</RequestId>
    <HostId>JGW6l8G9kFNfPgSuecFb6y9mh7IgJh28c5HKJbiP6qLLwvrHmESF1H5Y1PbFPAdv</HostId>
</Error>
```

Here is an example of what the Heroku sources endpoint API output looks like:

```
{ source_blob: 
   { get_url: 'https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-sources-production/heroku.com/2c6641c3-af40-4d44-8cdb-c44ee5f670c2?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJURUZ6XB34ESX54A&Signature=hYYNQ1WjwHqyyO0QMtjVXYBvsJg%3D&Expires=1424156543',
     put_url: 'https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-sources-production/heroku.com/2c6641c3-af40-4d44-8cdb-c44ee5f670c2?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJURUZ6XB34ESX54A&Signature=ecj4bxLnQL%2FZr%2FSKx6URJMr6hPk%3D&Expires=1424156543'
   }
}
```

**Update**

The key issue here is that the PUT request I send with the `request` module should be the same as the one sent with `curl` because I know that the `curl` request matches the expectations of the [AWS S3 Uploading Objects Using Pre-Signed URLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html) API.  Heroku generates the PUT url so I have no control over its creation.  I do know that the `curl` command works as I have tested it -- which is good since it is the example provided by Heroku.

I am using `curl` 7.35.0 and `request` 2.53.0.

Answer (score 2):

The Amazon API doesn't like chunked uploads.  The file needs to be sent unchunked.  So here is the code that works:

```
// PUT tarball
function(source, cb){
  console.log('Uploading tarball...');
  putUrl = source.source_blob.put_url;
  urlObj = url.parse(putUrl);

  fs.readFile(config.build.temp + 'archive.tar.gz', function(err, data){
    if (err){ cb(err); }
    else {
      var options = {
        body   : data,
        method : 'PUT',
        url    : urlObj
      };

      request(options, function(err, incoming, response){
        if (err){ cb(err); } else { cb(null, source); }
      });
    }
  });
},
```